# CSS pseudo-code is not recognised by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

my CSS pseudo-code is not recognised by jQuery: here's my code

css:

```
h1 {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

h1:after {
    content:" | ";
    background:blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

then in jQuery i do:

```
console.log($('h1').css('backgroundColor'));
```

is shows:

`rgb(255, 0, 0)`

but when i do:

```
console.log($('h1:after').css('backgroundColor'));
```

is shows:

`undefined`

Comment: I'm not sure you can. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651739/how-to-access-css-generated-content-with-javascript That said, you are using jQuery. If you're already using jQuery, why bother with the CSS :after? Just insert your content using jQuery to begin with.

Comment: Because the pseudo code is already there and I need to change the background color and other properties.

Comment: That's my point. If you use jQuery to insert the content, you can change all the styles before you even insert it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot select css pseudo-elements because they don't actually exist in the DOM