# CSS or jQuery for access to parent of element:before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering is there a way to access to `parent:before` of a element with `css` or jQuery or..? I should make `:before` of `li` display: none if a has TopNavActive class, in this code I should hide before if a has TopNavActive Class.

```
<li>::before 
    <a class="TopNavActive" href="/Cat14/14.html">
    Mobile
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Not directly, pseudo-elements (before, after, etc) are not accessible through JavaScript, and CSS cannot select parent elements, at least not yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access CSS generated content with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651739/how-to-access-css-generated-content-with-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

**JS:**

```
$('.TopNavActive').parent('li').addClass('MyTarget');
```

**CSS:**

```
.MyTarget::before {
    display: none!important;
}
```