# How do I get reference to the ::before or ::after node in JS?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

As far as I know, standard JavaScript has no way to get at the `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements. [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) doesn't let you get to it.

I know there has to be a way, at least in Chrome-privileged Firefox add-on code, since it lists every `::before` element in the page (and apparently [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) works on it too, as you can list all styles of it in [inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector), which is written in JavaScript).

Where is this API documented, and is it something that's different and privileged-only in say Firefox and Chrome browser, or something that is on track to be standard soon?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is not clear *exactly* what you want. Perhaps describe what you are trying to do. Are you wanting to insert content `::before` and `::after` the current node (this is what the CSS selectors `::before` and `::after` do)? Alternately, are you trying to walk the DOM tree that you see visually represented in the [Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector)?

Comment: Yes, I want to see *all* the nodes when programmatically going through dom.

Comment: So... your question is still not clear to me. Are you trying to gain access to `content` that *was* added using CSS `::before` & `::after`, or are you attempting to traverse the DOM tree getting access to elements/nodes which are prior to or later than the current element? I guess the thing that is confusing me is that you keep calling the `::before` and `::after` `content` "node" and "element" when this `content` is neither an element nor node, they are pseudo-elements which are not elements in the DOM. That combined with the tags you have used makes what you are asking unclear to me.

Answer (score 4):

The CSS generated content is not part of the DOM, and you wouldn't be able to do much with the `::before`/`::after` pseudo-elements, even if you get at them. The only use-cases I can think of are:

- **Access the CSS computed values on the pseudo-elements.** [window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) supports this via an optional 2nd parameter.
- **Enumerate the generated content**. You can accomplish this:

  - by using a browser-specific API. In Firefox, the DevTools inspector [uses](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/af7c0cb0798f/devtools/server/actors/inspector.js#l1405) a special interface - [inIDeepTreeWalker](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/inspector/inIDeepTreeWalker.idl).
  - or by walking the DOM and checking (for each element) if it has `content` in its computed style for `:before` / `:after`. For example:

    ```
    window.getComputedStyle(elt, ':before').content
    ```
- **Get the "live" value of a counter defined in CSS**, like in [How to access CSS generated content with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651739/how-to-access-css-generated-content-with-javascript) - see that question for details.

Answer (score 2):

At least to me, your question is unclear as to *exactly* what you are attempting to do, or get.

### The most direct equivalent to `::before` and `::after`:

If you are wanting to actually *insert content*, which is what the `::before` and `::after` CSS selectors do, then the most direct equivalent is [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). In that case:

The equivalent of `::before` would be:

```
Element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<p>Additional HTML content before element.</p>");
```

The equivalent of `::after` would be:

```
Element.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<p>Additional HTML content after element.</p>");
```

`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()` also has options of `afterbegin` and `beforeend` which insert the HTML text just after the beginning, or just before the end, of the referenced [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

#### Alternately:

You could insert nodes using [`Node.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
For `::before` it would be (insert `newNode` before myNode):

```
myNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, myNode);
```

For `::after` it would be (insert `newNode` after myNode):

```
myNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, myNode.nextSibling);
```

### Obtaining references:

If you are attempting to get a reference to the element that is earlier in the DOM, then it sounds like you are looking for [`Node.previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling). If you are looking for a reference to the element that is later in the DOM, then you are looking for [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).

#### In DOM walk order:

It is also possible that you are looking for the elements that are just before and just after the reference [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) in [*DOM walk order*](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/traversal.html).  However, that is **not** really what the CSS selectors `::before` and `::after` do. However, from your mention of [Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector), it kind of sounds like this is what you want. If so, then you will can use a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to walk the DOM tree.

The following should do what you want (Note: Currently untested, so might be missing something.):

```
//referenceNode is the node for which we want to find the elements
//  before and after in DOM walk order.

//Create the TreeWalker
let treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
                                           {acceptNode: function(node) { 
                                                            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
                                                        }
                                            }, 
                                            false );
//Point the TreeWalker at the referenceNode. 
treeWalker.currentNode = referenceNode;
//Get the node immediately prior to the referenceNode in DOM walk order
let thePreviousNode = treeWalker.previousNode();

//Point the TreeWalker back at the referenceNode.
treeWalker.currentNode = referenceNode;
//Get the node immediately after to the referenceNode in DOM walk order
let theNextNode = treeWalker.nextNode();
```

As mentioned by [Nickolay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026/nickolay), if you want the full detail that Page Inspector, or the [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Add-ons/DOM_Inspector)), provides then you will need to use an [inIDeepTreeWalker](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/inspector/inIDeepTreeWalker.idl). However, it is unlikely that you want, or need, the detail which using that Firefox specific non-standard interface provides. You only need it if you want to walk through how something like how an XUL [`<toolbarbutton>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/toolbarbutton) is constructed (not the attributes/properties, but the [XBL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XBL) which makes up a XUL elements like a `<toolbarbutton>`). For the vast majority of what you are potentially thinking about, a standard TreeWalker should be just fine.

With the exception of `inIDeepTreeWalker`, all of the above are standard parts of JavaScript and do not require elevated privileges (i.e do not require it to be in an add-on).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `iniDOMUtils` - `selectorMatchesElement()` function.

You can read more about it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/inIDOMUtils#selectorMatchesElement%28%29

Comment: How will finding out if an element (which you already have) matches a selector help you get a psuedo-element in the first place?