# Add class when div:after content equals "0"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple `ul` list with some number of `li` elements - some of them have specific class `.count`.

Using CSS `counter()` function I'm counting number of `li.count` and displaying it as a `content: counter()` for `#result:after`.

And now is the problem - if the number of `li.count` equals **0** I want to  remove `.hidden` class from `#message`.

```
    <ul id="list">
        <li class=""> ... </li>
        <li class=""> ... </li>
        <li class=""> ... </li>
        <li class=""> ... </li>
        <li class=""> ... </li>
        <li class="count"> ... </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="result"> ... </div>

    <p id="message" class="hidden"> ... </p>
```

I was trying to do some JQuery for that but I'm not quite sure if I made some mistakes or if this **0** from `#result:after {content: counter()}` is a real value for the browser.

Comment: I think you need counter value to check in java script and then have to make any decision to remove class so this link talks about some way to deal with this problem, hope this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651739/how-to-access-css-generated-content-with-javascript

Comment: @AlivetoDie - thank you for this message - I didn't know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said:- `if the number of li.count equals 0 I want to remove .hidden class from #message.`

You can do it like below:-

```
if($('li.count').length ==0){
 $('#message').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

example 1:-https://jsfiddle.net/yvyj14kw/

example 2:- https://jsfiddle.net/1k81m56c/

Comment: We are almost there. The situation is a little bit more complicated so I wanted to use `counter()` value. My `li`'s have more classes so counting only `li.count` doesn't works.

Is there a chance to add somes specific style value to `li.count`? For example: count all `li.count` elements that also have property `display:block` in CSS file

Comment: @MarcinWasilewicz  it's possible. But pls ask a new question regarding that with proper HTML input and your code effort what you tried so far to solve your problem. You will get answer for-sure. You can address me the  link too, and if i have time i will try to answer too

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I found the way how to do that but it is wrong concept (it is my fault). JQuery checks it once while loading page but in my case number of `li`'s is changing when user does some actions on page. I need to think on some other solution. Thanks one more time!

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" id="countitems">Count Number of List Items in following List</a>
    <ul id="list">
        <li class=""> ... </li>
        <li class=""> ... </li>
        <li class=""> ... </li>
        <li class=""> ... </li>
        <li class=""> ... </li>
        <li class=""> ... </li>
  </ul>
 <div id='hidden'>There are no childrens </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    if ($('#list').children('li.count').length === 0) {
        $('#hidden').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use below piece of code

```
var count = 0;
        $('#list li.count').each(function(){
            count++;
        });
        if(count == 0) {
            $('#message').removeClass('hidden');
        }
```