# Get pseudo elements counter next value

Tags: javascript, css, list, pseudo-element, css-counter

How can i get the incremental value of pseudo element's counter value.

```
counter(my-Counter-Variable , cjk-ideographic)
```

Is there any way in JavaScript to get the value of above counter content.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access CSS generated content with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651739/how-to-access-css-generated-content-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to get the pseudo-element's `content` property using `window.getComputedStyle()` on the originating element (see [How to access CSS generated content with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651739/how-to-access-css-generated-content-with-javascript)), and if the `content` property doesn't contain just the counter itself then you'll need to parse the value out of whatever string actually makes up the pseudo-element's `content` property. CSS doesn't expose the counter itself directly to you.