# How to get pseudo element's computed value?

Tags: javascript, chromium, puppeteer

I have a counter in a psuedo class in my CSS, something like this,

```
h2::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Section " counter(section) ": ";
}
```

and I want the computed value of counter.

I have tried using

`getComputedStyles(document.getElementById("1"), '::before')`

but that returns `Section " counter(section) ":`, whereas I am trying to get the actual value that it displays. which is `Section 1:`

This is the demo HTML snippet that I have been testing with,

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(section) ": ";
}
```

```html
<h2 id="1">HTML Tutorial</h2>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access CSS generated content with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651739/how-to-access-css-generated-content-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately with current CSS specification it isn't possible. See why and what to do instead [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2652144/2715393)