# Is there a javascript shorthand for accessing an element's css counter variable by name?

Tags: javascript, html, css-variables

I have a chess board with a counter variable for its fields. It is initialized using counter-reset and -1, and increments by one per field. Now I am trying to access that css counter variable using something that's not a :before or :after hack.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to access a CSS counter from JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access CSS generated content with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651739/how-to-access-css-generated-content-with-javascript)