# CSS - adding text to the styles in stylesheet

Tags: css

I haven't found any documentation yet, so I don't think it's doable. 
But it's worth asking.

Can I specify actual Text inside a style, within the stylesheet?

I have a few places that use the same text in the same div places. And instead of using javascript or retyping the same text in the divs, I was pondering if styles can have actual "text" inserted inside.

```
.someclass {
  text:"for example";  /* this is how I'd imagine it, IF it were possible */
  color:#000;
}
```

I might be pushing this one.

Comment: Related: [What are good uses of css "Content" property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435513/what-are-good-uses-of-css-content-property)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for the [content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content) property.

Unfortunately, it can only be used with pseudo-elements.

> This property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements to generate content in a document.

So you could do something like...

```
.someclass:before {
   content: "This text will be added at the beginning of the element"
}
.someclass:after {
   content: "This text will be added at the end of the element"
}
```

Comment: More about pseudo-elements than about the `content` property, but [Nicolas Gallagher has done some amazing stuff, creating pure CSS icons](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/demo/). Extremely impressive; extremely cool.

Answer (score 7):

you can use this approach with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements

```
.someclass:after {
  content:"for example";
  color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use before or after pseudo-class to acheive this:
For example:

```
.someclass:before{ 
    content:"for example";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that could be done in CSS. But in jQuery it would look like :

```
$('.someclass').html("for example");
```