# How to change the content of a span using css hover?

Tags: css

I can set the text of a span with this css.

```
.tracking-true .tracking-button-text:before
{
    content:"Tracking";
}
```

But I would like to change the text on hover
Something like this but I can't get it to work.

```
.tracking-true .tracking-button-text:hover
{
    content:"Untrack";
}
```

Can this be done in css?

Update:
Much like Stackoverflow uses :hover to change the cursor to a pointer or change a background color as a ui hint I am trying to convey to the user the same thing. This element can be clicked on and something will happen.
I don't feel this is an innaporopriate use of CSS.

Comment: I would have to ask "why do you want to do this?". CSS should be used to styling the content, not for actual content :P Also, along the same lines as what @AarolamaBluenk said, you can do this with JavaScript, not necessarily jQuery.

Comment: I'm with @sweetamylase Css is for styling, don't use it to create functionality.... you will just get yourself into a world of trouble. and make a mess for whoever comes after you.

Comment: "The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements to generate content in an element." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/content - this is the only context in which the property can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
.tracking-true .tracking-button-text:before
{
    content:"Tracking";
}

.tracking-true .tracking-button-text:hover:before
{
    content:"Untrack";
}
```

Comment: Should discourage the use of CSS for anything that's not styling. :(

Comment: Discouraging is a different topic. He wants an answer here it is. You are not contributing.

Comment: It may work, but it's an abuse of the `content` property in CSS. And I'm sure it's ompletely frowned upon in the web community.

Comment: StackOverflow is a place where people can learn and improve. If someone is going down the wrong path, it would be best to point them toward the right direction.

Comment: At least add to your answer and warn people that they shouldn't be doing this with their CSS.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down. Downvoting for what you think is not a "proper guideline" is not along the lines of what should be downvoted.

Comment: I have read it. Your answer isn't complete, and people might come along and think it's ok to do what you wrote. Also, it's not just "my guideline", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435513/what-are-good-uses-of-css-content-property

Comment: Your measure of "ok" is subjective and highly open to debate. You can find about a million articles of people saying content is good or bad and when to use it or not. This is not the place to preach dogma. Please read the answers to the question you linked. It is an open discussion.

Comment: Not saying it has to be explicitly written and declared to be "OK". But generally, other fellow web developers would appreciate it if people don't abuse CSS. It's for the common good.

Comment: "For the common good" has no relevance here. This site is not intended to be a soap box. It is for questions and answers.

Comment: Someday when you have to work on a site that someone else has built, and they use their CSS in ways that you don't expect, you'll realize why people try to push others to use CSS properly and appropriately.

Comment: In this application, the words "Tracking" and "Untrack" are functional descriptors, and do not constitute content.  This use is more like roll-over-images, a visual indicator of something-to-do or something-is-happening; I would say this is a user interface design/styling issue so using CSS is okay.

Comment: Although I'm not generally comfortable with changing content using CSS, I've upvoted this one because a) it correctly answers the question as given and crucially b) the content being changed or inserted appear to be UI hints rather than actual page context as Marc states.